# VS 2022 Preview 3 Breaks MAUI Apps on IPhone That Use Azure REST Services

Tags: maui

I just updated Visual Studio from 2022 Preview 2 to Preview 3.  My MAUI app calls REST services that I host in Azure, i.e. on a azurewebsites.net domain.  When I upgraded to Preview 3, it also updated/reinstalled mobile SDKs for Android and IOS.

Everything is still working on the Android simulator, but when I try the app on an IOS device, it fails now when trying to connect to my REST service hosted in Azure.  The error it gives is "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.".

The InnerException is a System.EntryPointNotFoundException, and the Message associated with it is "SystemNative_GetDefaultTimeZone".  I've not been able to find this error reported elsewhere, but my whole IOS apps is dead in the water.  Has anyone else seen this error after upgrading to Preview 3, or in any other circumstances and know exactly what needs to be changed?

Here is the full error stack:

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: SystemNative_GetDefaultTimeZone
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.TryGetLocalTzFile(Byte[]& rawData, String& id)
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.GetLocalTimeZoneFromTzFile()
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.GetLocalTimeZoneCore()
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.GetLocalTimeZone(CachedData cachedData)
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.CachedData.CreateLocal()
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.CachedData.get_Local()
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.get_Local()
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.GetDateTimeNowUtcOffsetFromUtc(DateTime time, Boolean& isAmbiguousLocalDst)
   at System.DateTime.get_Now()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainPolicy.Reset()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainPolicy..ctor()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.get_ChainPolicy()
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(RemoteCertificateValidationCallback remoteCertValidationCallback, SslCertificateTrust trust, ProtocolToken& alertToken, SslPolicyErrors& sslPolicyErrors, X509ChainStatusFlags& chainStatus)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(ProtocolToken& alertToken, SslPolicyErrors& sslPolicyErrors, X509ChainStatusFlags& chainStatus)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ForceAuthenticationAsync>d__175`1[[System.Net.Security.AsyncReadWriteAdapter, System.Net.Security, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.<WaitWithCancellationAsync>d__1[[System.Net.Http.HttpConnection, System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at MyApp.Utilities.TokenHelper.Authenticate(String authState) in C:\Users\spesc\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\MyApp\Utilties\TokenHelper.cs:line 85}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this because I think it's likely that other people may hit this same error.  In researching the Exception type (EntryPointNotFoundException), it described scenarios such as a mismatched DLL assembly.  So to fix this, I did the following:

1. Clean the solution
2. Delete everything out of the obj folder
3. Delete everything out of the debug folder
4. Run and deploy again

After doing so, the app started working on IOS devices.